# Add a Function to Existing Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to be able to amend my already existing formulas and add them new functions in mass. For example, I originally wrote a calculation

```
=Sheet1!D38-Sheet1!E38
```

and would like to add an `=IFERROR` so it looks like this:

```
=IFERROR(Sheet1!D38-Sheet1!E38, 0%)
```

which is relatively easy to do manually when you have one or two of them but I have a whole document with formulas to be amended.

**Is there an easy way of adding a new function to existing formulas without going through all of them one by one?**

The presented example is random; I might have to do it with longer and more complex formulas like `=COUNTIFS`

The *quick* fix I have tried before consisted on:

1. Find and replace all the `=` at the beginning of the formula with `#` - this would convert the formula in plain text
2. Copy and paste the second part of the new formula, the one that would go at the end, in every single cell. In this case it would be `, 0%)`
3. Substitute the `#` with `=IFERROR(` to have the formula back, with the additional information I wanted

But this is not a very efficient way of doing it.

Comment: If you could show what you are working with it could help. For example, all I could do is shoot in the dark and assume that the first formula looks exactly like the second formula... with the exception of E38 is now E39, in that case all you would have to do is change one formula then copy/paste (or select/drag/pull down method or any number of ways to copy formula downwards) the rest and Excel will change the row numbers. But if that's not the case there could be any number of random ways you use any formula.

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute in 2 steps, without manual editing:
1- search&replace `=` with `=IFERROR(`
(this will produce a lot of errors)
2- search&replace the line end with `,0%)`
Enter the following 2 keystrokes for the line end:
Control-M
Control-J

Note that you won't see any character on entry but it'll work.

Comment: But if I do the first step, a window pops-up saying that I am missing a parenthesis and doesn't let me change the formula at all (it goes back to what it was). That is why I added the step of transforming it into text with # . Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: In my version (German, 2003) it adds the closing parantheses automatically while replacing. Can you try reversing the steps?

Comment: I'm using the British 2010 and it tells me it can't find the data when I try the Ctrl M and Ctrol J, as if there really wasn' any character

Answer (score 0):

I generally use [regex add-in](http://www.codedawn.com/excel-add-ins.php) to manipulate text with more flexibility than built in search / replace.

It provides both find / replace and also worksheet functions with regular expressions.

In your example you need to

- look for: `=(.*)`
- replace to: `=iferror($1,0%)`

Note that this add-in doesn't have the functionality to replace only in selection, so you need to take care to write specific enough look for expression.

Comment: I can't download it since the work computer identifies it as risk. I have tried with an "Essential Excel Add-In" that included the regex but does not seem to work. Do you have an alternative link by any chance?

Comment: no, I don't have another link for it:(. Can you download on another pc and copy it to your working one?

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a group of cells we which to edit en-mass:

[image]

We select the cells and run this short macro:

```
Sub FixFormula()
'
'   hi-light the cells you wish to process
'
    Dim r As Range, rngF As Range, s As String

    Set rngF = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    For Each r In rngF
        s = "(" & Mid(r.Formula, 2) & ")"
        r.Formula = "=IFERROR(" & s & ","""")"
    Next r
End Sub
```

and all the formulas will convert from:

```
=A1/B1
```

to:

```
=IFERROR((A1/B1),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

A **temporary** solution to demonstrate a possible fix; see image. But **stipulations on my comment**.

**Copy/Paste formula, Click and Hold method.**
[image]